# Where is the code correspoding to the changes made in qt designer located?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt4, qt5

I'm using:
Qt 5.2.1, Qt Creator 3.2.1

Using the designer mode inside the qt creator, I created two widgets:
1. Horizontal slider
2. Spin Box

Then using the Signal and Slots editor I did the following:
1. Sender: horizontal slider
2. signal: value changed
3. receiver: spinBox
4. slot: setValue

Then I built and ran the project and it worked the way I had expected it to.
But in the files that qt shows in the left pane, there is no corresponding code for these two widgets though the widgets work fine when the project is run.

Where is the code corresponding to the widgets and the signals and slots that I created is located?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually there is a building folder beside your project which contains auto generated files.

For example, for a form with name `MyForm.ui`, it makes `ui_MyForm.h` that has `connect` commands corresponding to the signal/slots.

Comment: When I use designer, it just appends the code to the .ui file and it is not editable from the qt creator workspace directly (designer mode has to be used for this). Another method is writing down the code manually in the main cpp files. Which is the preferred method - using qt designer or writing code on my own? If there has to be a mixture, what is the ratio of things I should do with each?

Comment: I prefer to write all signal/slots in my cpp files to have a better control and avoid depending on code generators.

Comment: thanks, so a good mixture will be to add the widgets using the designer and then use the connect commands manually in the cpp files to control how they behave while having all the properties of the widgets in the auto generated files?

Comment: Yes, I'm using this way without any problem in my projects.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler generates the code from the form.  In my case, my form is named `dialog.ui` and the generated file is named `ui_dialog.h`.  You can find it in the `ui` folder under where the compiler builds your code.  It'll be a different place depending on if you use shadow build or not.

Comment: When I use designer, it just appends the code to the .ui file and it is not editable from the qt creator workspace directly (designer mode has to be used for this). Another method is writing down the code manually in the main cpp files. Which is the preferred method - using qt designer or writing code on my own? If there has to be a mixture, what is the ratio of things I should do with each?

Comment: They are really two separate things.  You should never really need to worry about the code generated from the form, you just use the items it provides in your application code.  As an example, you add a ListView to a form and then write the C++ code to create a model and attach it to the ListView.  The only thing you need to know is what you named the ListView.  There's no real ratio to aim for, just use the tool most appropriate for the job.

Comment: ok thanks. So I should just add the widgets using the designer and all its properties being handled by the auto generated code while the connect commands should be in the cpp files added manually to determine the behavior of the widgets?